# Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore MySql null reference exception. ASP.Net core 1.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

I have a database and an app on asp.net core, when I moved the database and application to another computer when I added the migration, I faced the following problem:

```
Add-Migration InitialCreate -context MySqlDbContext
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.CloseDatabase()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.DoClose()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnection.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.MySqlConnectionSettings.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<GetSettings>b__0(String key)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.MySqlScopedTypeMapper.get_ConnectionSettings()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.MySqlScopedTypeMapper.MaybeConvertMapping(RelationalTypeMapping mapping)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalTypeMapperExtensions.IsTypeMapped(IRelationalTypeMapper typeMapper, Type clrType)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereArrayIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.PropertyDiscoveryConvention.Apply(InternalEntityTypeBuilder entityTypeBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.OnEntityTypeAdded(InternalEntityTypeBuilder entityTypeBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.Model.AddEntityType(EntityType entityType, Boolean runConventions)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.InternalModelBuilder.Entity(Type type, ConfigurationSource configurationSource, Boolean runConventions)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder.Entity(Type type)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.FindSets(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, DbContext context)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.RelationalModelSource.FindSets(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, DbContext context)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, IModelValidator validator)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.LazyRef`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitTransient(TransientCallSite transientCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitTransient(TransientCallSite transientCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

How I connect to database :

```
public class MySqlDbContext : DbContext
{
    public static DbContextOptions<MySqlDbContext> Options;

    public MySqlDbContext(DbContextOptions<MySqlDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
        Options = options;
    }

    [ThreadStatic]
    protected static MySqlDbContext current;

    public static MySqlDbContext Current()
    {
        if (current == null)
            current = new MySqlDbContext(Options);

        return current;
    }

    ...
}



public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<MySqlDbContext>(
       options => options.UseMySql(mysqlConnection)
    );
}

  "ConnectionStrings": {
"MiddleWareMySqlProvider": "server=localhost;port=3306;Uid=root;password=root;Database=idapdb2;persistsecurityinfo=True; Pooling=false; convert zero datetime=True"
  },
```

I thought the problem was with the connection string, but in other applications everything works fine.

I don't know how solve this problem.

Comment: Why target 1.1?

Comment: @kennyzx the application was written before me. Change version is not possible

Comment: @temiklis is your `UseMySql` behaving as expected? Are you sure about using [ServiceLifeTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicelifetime?view=aspnetcore-2.1) defaults?

Comment: @RuiFernandes I'm not sure, but it seems to be yes

Comment: changed provider from pomelo.entityframeworkcore.mysql to mysql.data.entityframework, it worked! However, this is not the solution to my problem.